# How to implement IObjectSafety for untrusted callers

Tags: internet-explorer, com, activex, atl

I have an ActiveX control written in C++ using ATL that has a couple of unsafe methods (reading and writing files.)

I've looked at the [IObjectSafety](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768224%28v=vs.85%29) interface but it is not clear if I can protect individual methods or not.  Since the control is mostly used via the `IDispatch` interface, I do not wish to mark the whole interface as unsafe.

Is there a good tutorial on the interface and how it is used by InternetExplorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IObjectSafety` marks interfaces, not individual methods. If you look at its syntax, you will see that the arguments do not provide flexibility to mark individual methods.

```
HRESULT SetInterfaceSafetyOptions(
    REFIID riid,
    DWORD dwOptionSetMask,
    DWORD dwEnabledOptions
);
```

See also: [How To IObjectSafety Marks ATL Controls Safe for Initializing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168371).

Comment: So I'm feeling pretty stupid and feel I need a reference describing its use.  Why would the client call the SetInterfaceSafetlyOptions, I would have expected the client to be calling GetInterfaceSafetlyOptions.

Comment: `GetInterfaceSafetlyOptions` returns supported and enabled options. `SetInterfaceSafetlyOptions` allows to enable/disable options that are supported. The point is that object owner would use `SetInterfaceSafetlyOptions` to initialize the object (before use) to specify certain mode of operation. If the object does not implement the interface, IE would ask user for confirmation. Otherwise, it would enable the mode programmatically and run silently assuming the control takes care of safety.

Comment: This is starting to make sense.  If `SetInterfaceSafetlyOptions` is called passed `INTERFACESAFE_FOR_UNTRUSTED_CALLER` then am I correct in believing my unsafe functions should then fail, and in the absence of the call they are safe to run?  Many thanks for the help.